# webpack css can't import from exclude directory

Tags: webpack

In my webpack config rules I excluded /node_modules/

```
test : /\.css$/,
exclude : /node_modules/,
```

in my css file I tried importing a 3rd party library in node_modules and got the error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> @font-face {
| font-family: 'KaTeX_AMS';
| src: url(fonts/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(fonts/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.woff) format('woff'), url(fonts/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
```

my whole config
https://github.com/defuyun/issue-sample/blob/master/webpack.config.js

my css file

```
import Katex from 'katex';
import 'katex/dist/katex.css'
```

here's a repo with the issue reproduced
https://github.com/defuyun/issue-sample